# Is there research on optimal control/command strategy/hierachy?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, mission-control

On manned-missions which take its participants further and further into space it will be quite difficult to have a control center on Earth as it takes longer an longer to communicate.

It takes the light around 8 minutes to travel from the surface of the sun to Earth. Without any delay this would be 16 minutes for two-way communication and there's surely a point/zone on/in which it will be impractical to communicate.

Is there research on this topic?

For example:

> "For missions with 'M' crew members that will take its crew 'X' AU
>   (astronomical unit[s]) away from Earth it is reasonable to have
>   mission control solely on Earth. The crew members are not allowed to
>   make mission-critical decisions on their own"
>
> "For missions with 'M' crew members that will take its crew 'Y' AU
>   away from Earth it is reasonable to have a hybrid-solution. After 'X'
>   AU (...). Crew members should decide democratically."
>
> "For missions with 'M' crew members that will take its crew 'Z' AU
>   away form Earth it is reasonable to have mission control solely in the
>   hands of the crew. It's recommended to base this on a hybrid solution.
>   After 'Y' AU (...). When 'M' exceeds 'N' high ranked members voices
>   count twice."

Comment: The ship's captain (or master) have all final decisions. Even within communication range.

Answer (score 2):

There is this work at USC, ["Research to explore communication delays in space"](http://news.usc.edu/#!/article/43871/research-to-explore-psychological-effects-of-communication-delays-in-space/), going on right now under a NASA grant. The investigation is being supervised by Professor Lawrence Palinkas:

> The three-year study will involve simulating communication lag between
>   astronauts on the International Space Station and ground control staff
>   to determine how crew members cope with stressful situations and new
>   forms of isolation.
>
> [...]
>
> Crew members will be asked to perform a set of specific tasks during
>   the course of four weeks, split between the beginning and end of their
>   six-month stay on the space station. During two of those weeks,
>   they’ll experience a 50-second delay in interaction with mission
>   control.
>
> In addition, the jobs will vary in terms of how novel and critical
>   they are in nature — that is, whether the astronauts received any
>   training for each task and whether each situation is life-threatening
>   or menial. “Cleaning out the toilet is not novel or critical,”
>   Palinkas said, “but responding to a medical emergency could be.”
>
> [...]
>
> Palinkas is hopeful that findings from the project will prove useful
>   in terms of improving training programs for astronauts to handle
>   anxiety and stress, as well as developing technology that helps
>   mitigate the negative effects of communication delays.